# Generating LLC Tank Gain Curves within Open Loop Simulation - SIMPLIS

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, simulation, llc-converter

I'm using the half bridge LLC open loop circuit mr. basso very kindly gave to the world, but I am having troubles generating the tank gain curves. I'm somewhat of a novice when it comes to SIMPLIS and setting up the POP simulations.... I've attached images showing the circuit I currently have setup (I've just added the POP trigger and bode plot generator), and simulation setups. I've also attached the error I'm getting along with some waveforms. The X-axis (which isn't shown....) vertical bold lines are 100uS/div.

The POP trigger Maximum period I believe is correct, since 150K switching frequency is 6.6uS (I've set Max period to 7uS).

One place I know I have a mistake is where to put the AC source for AC simulation, I don't know where to place it here... So, help here would be great. Also, if you see other mistakes, please let me know. Cheers

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, I plead guilty for releasing these circuits : ) If you want the classical LLC resonant tank curves, you will have to resort to an ac analysis with a SPICE simulator. The circuit you've shown cannot run an ac analysis since the switching frequency is fixed. It has been thought for checking the LLC components values, to see if they bring the right operating point at the considered Fsw. You may find more details on the LLC in this [AN](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND8255-D.PDF) that I wrote at the time I defined the NCP1395, a low-voltage LLC controller.

Comment: A a side note, the curves you refer to correspond to the *dc transfer characteristics* of the LLC, not to be confused with the *control-to-output* transfer function. The first ones give you the circuit gain - e.g. what \$V_{out}\$ for given \$V_{in}\$ - in relationship with the switching frequency. It is an ac-swept dc characteristic. The second transfer function is the small-signal response of the LLC for loop control purposes. You can obtain it by using another template either featuring a voltage-controlled oscillator (VCO) or other indirect frequency control techniques (CM, bang-bang).

Comment: Senior basso! Both your comments per usual make complete sense, thanks! Two questions: 1) Is this the software you used to develop that model in (http://www.intusoft.com/demos.htm)? 2) would you be willing to part with that model?

Comment: I can share this model but I haven't tried it for a while as I no longer use Intusoft. If you Google "LLC design tools", you will find many free tools that should plot the dc transfer characteristics you want.

Comment: Okay great, through chat or will you update your website? I have made my own via octave that is pretty good, but being able to use simulation with circuit elements feels a bit more secure.

Comment: Just looked at it, it's too old stuff and it won't run on the demo I'm afraid. Did you check some of the available online tools like this one from [NXP](https://www.nxp.com/products/power-management/ac-dc-solutions/ac-dc-controllers/llc-resonant-converter-design-tool:LLC-RESONANT-CONVERTER-DST).